# What actions earn credits?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Credits are used to purchase things like additional levels (that I've found so far). You can get more through microtransactions though I'd rather avoid this option:

[image]

What in game actions allow you to earn credits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Completing a quest from the Emperor.
2. Completing a quest from Vader.
3. Taking a bitizen to their requested floor in the elevator.
4. Stocking an item in a shop (Food, Retail, Recreation, Service) will lead to credits as it will then be sold.
5. Rent being payed by the occupants of a residential level.
6. Taking a Big Spender to a shop with 1 or more products.

Answer (score 0):

Additional methods -

Fully stocking a level results in a small bonus of credits.

Bringing a ? bitizen to their desired level will give you double the normal tip and trigger a small buying frenzy.

You can also exchange Bux for credits.